# Is it possible to pass system properties to unit tests run by Hudson?

Tags: maven-2, hudson

We're using Maven 2 and Hudson, and everything is working well.  My question is it possible to have Hudson run all the unit tests in a particular project with a specific "-D" argument.  For example, "mvn test -DlogConfig=qa".  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In a project configuration page there's section "Build" and text field "Goals and options" where you can place that "-D argument" and goals that you want to run.